# Loop through FormCollection with index and key name to get value

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, key-value, formcollection

I am trying to loop through a FormCollection where I want to specify the index and key of the formcollection but am not having luck.
**FormCollection Keys Example**

```
form[0][keyA]
form[0][keyB]
form[0][keyC]
form[1][keyA]
...
```

And I am trying to loop using but I understand it isn't correct since im running into an error trying to convert from string to an int. Is there an alternative loop I can use to achieve what I need?

```
       for (int i = 0; i < form.AllKeys.Count(); i++)
        {
            var key1A = form[i]["keyA"]
            var key1B = form[i]["keyB"]
            ....
        }
```

Comment: You are running into an error converting string to int? So why do you think your error is related to your loop then?

Comment: Well it makes me think that I am not getting the value correctly, and was wondering if theres another method of getting both key and index?

Comment: How would we know, if you don't show us the code, that is throwing the error?